# TreeMap#containsKey return false just after put

Tags: java, treemap, containskey

I know this question has been treated before but I've read questions and tried to fix my own with no result, I think I'm missing something with the TreeMap or Map implementation...

```
if(arme != null){
    if(!hommesArmes.containsKey(arme)){
        System.out.println(hommesArmes.containsKey(arme));
        hommesArmes.put(arme, new TreeSet<Homme>());
        System.out.println(hommesArmes.containsKey(arme));
    }
    hommesArmes.get(arme).add(homme);
}
```

Why do I get false twice when I run this? I've tried with Integer instead of Arme and it worked, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The class used as the key (Arme) doesn't implement Comparable correctly. Or the comparator you used when constructing the TreeMap is wrong. Post the relevant code.

Comment: That's exactly what I was going to write, I just discovered I had a problem with the Comparator object I passed to its constructor.

Comment: What kind of object have you assigned to arme?

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the Comparator object I passed to the constructor of my TreeMap.